# How to fork and splice route prefix?

Tags: php, laravel

Consider the following:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'system'), function()
{
    Route::resource('accounts', 'UserController');
    Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
}
```

How could I fork `system` to `admin` in a way that both will work exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$my_routes = function() {
    Route::resource('accounts', 'UserController');
    Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
};

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'system'), $my_routes);
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), $my_routes);
```

but I don't think there is a built in way in Laravel to do what you want. I guess a better question is, why would you want to do this?